# Fondo circular sobre un número

Tags: css

Tengo el problema cuando intento hacer un fondo circular sobre un número, que me sale como un óvalo. He mirado en varias webs pero me sigue saliendo un óvalo, en lugar de un circulo. Os dejo el código que estoy intentando, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a solucionarlo:

```css
#calendar .hoy {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;

}
```

Los números los saco por JavaScript, en este caso el código donde está el número es:

```
resultado += "<td class='hoy' ><a class='hoy' onclick='select_pordias(this.id," +
year + "," + month + ")' id=" + dia + ">" + dia + "</a></td>";
```

Me aparece así:

[image: Circulo]

Igual tiene que ver que cada número tiene un padding de 22px, pero esto lo debo tener si o si para que se separen correctamente los números del calendario. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Inserta el código donde está el número por favor.

Comment: Perdona, ya está

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo que lo hagas de esta manera:
En primer lugar hacemos el estilo y le colocamos el ancho y alto, en este caso 22px:

```
.hoy {
      height: 22px;
      width: 22px;
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #bbb;
    }
```

Y luego indicamos donde tiene que reflejar este círculo:

```
<div class="hoy">1</div>
```

Veo que lo tienes en un `<td>` así que puedes incorporarlo.

```css
.hoy {
      height: 22px;
      width: 22px;
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #bbb;
    }
```

```html
<div class="hoy">1</div>
```

Comment: Lo he puesto como me has dicho pero sigue sin salirme correctamente, me sale un óvalo de forma horizontal, voy a poner una imagen para que lo veas.

Comment: Eso es porque el estilo `class` lo tienes puesto en el `<td>`. Coloca el `<div>` dentro del `<td>`: `<td><div class="hoy"><a href="#">1</a></div></td>`

Comment: el tamaño del texto influirá en como se agranda el contenedor, probar con el texto `00`. y tal vez aplicar un `overflow: hidden`

Comment: @Jok lo he puesto así, pero sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: ¿el `<td>` tiene algún estilo declarado en el css? según la imagen rellena todo el ancho. También ten en cuenta lo que dice @aloMalbarez, aunque creo que no es ese el problema que tienes, ya que te lo estira de forma horizontal. Revisa bien el código.

Comment: Sí que lo tiene, pero lo he revisado y no afecta en nada...

Answer (score 2):

Manejando los tamaños de los contenedores se evita que se ovalicen, un tamaño de fuente mas grande puede añadir espacios horizontales, `display:block` o `inline-block` hacen que el ancho minimo se respete (el `a` es `inline` de fábrica )

```js
resultado = '<tr>';
var d = new Date();
var e = new Date();

for(var i = 0 - e.getDay(); i<30; i++) {
   d.setDate(e.getDate() + i);
   year = d.getFullYear();
   month = d.getMonth();
   dia = d.getDate();
   clase = (d.getDate()==e.getDate())?'hoy':'';
   resultado += "<td><a class='"+clase+"' onclick='select_pordias(this.id," +
       year + "," + month + ")' id=" + dia + ">" + dia + "</a></td>";
   if (d.getDay()==6) {resultado += '</tr><tr>';};
}
resultado += '</tr>';

$("#calendar tbody").append(resultado);
```

```css
#calendar td {
  margin:1px;
  padding:22px;
  border:1px dashed #ccc;
}
#calendar a {
  text-align: center;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  display:block;
  line-height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #afa;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#calendar .hoy {
  color: black;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="calendar">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lo que te falla es la dimensión del elemento

Para crear un cículo con CSS, lo que se hace es aplicar `border-radius: 50%` a los estilos del mismo. Esto significa que se va a crear una curva que va desde el 50% (la mitad) del borde superior (o inferior) hasta el 50% (de nuevo la mitad) del borde lateral. La versión extendida (o detallada de este estilo sería:

```css
div {

border-top-left-radius:     50%;
border-top-right-radius:    50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius:  50%;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}

.otro {
border-top-left-radius:     50%;
border-top-right-radius:    50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
border-bottom-left-radius:  0;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="otro"/>
```

Como puedes ver, podríamos aplicarlo sólo a ciertas esquinas

Para hacer un círculo perfecto, necesitas que las curvas sean arcos perfectos, es decir, que todos los lados sean iguales: **el elemento ha de ser un cuadrado perfecto** o no funcionará:

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
border-radius:     50%;
width: 70px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}

.otro {
border-radius:     25px;
width: 70px;
height: 50px;
background-color: blue;
}

.cuadrado {
border-radius:     35px;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="otro"></div>

<div class="cuadrado"></div>
```

La solución en tu caso sería meter cada número en un elemento con un tamaño fijo, donde la anchura sea igual a la altura en todo momento. Puesto que tienes los números en una tabla donde las celdas son rectangulares, podrías simplemente definir la altura y anchura en un div o span (o en el mismo `<a>`):

```js
const calendario= document.getElementById('calendario');
let dias=1;
for (let i=0;i<4;i++) {
  let semana='<tr>';
  for (let j=0;j<7;j++) {
    semana+=`<td><a href="#" class="hoy">${dias++}</a></td>`;
  }
  semana+='</tr>';
  calendario.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', semana );
}
```

```css
table {
width: 50%;
}

.hoy {
display: inline-block;
 height: 28px;
 width: 28px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: grey;
 font: 18px Helvetica;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 color: white;
 line-height: 30px; 
}
```

```html
<table id="calendario">
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, he visto que si le quito el padding de 22px que tengo en el th, si que me sale bien, pero no podría aplicar el padding de otra forma? Los span estan muy bien pero los números se crean de forma dinámica con javascript...

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta: como ves, puedes generar el código con JS sin problema.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he resuelto de una forma más facil...

```css
a.hoy{
   height: 28px;
      width: 28px;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #d7d7d7;
   padding-right:13px;
   padding-left:13px;
   padding-top: 4px;
}
```